# how to install openVRML in Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, vrml

I have tried macports:

```
port install openvrml
```

Also tried fink (with unstable tree configuration)

```
fink install openvrml6-xembed-dev
```

and both failed.

Also tried downloading the source form Sourceforge and don't know what do with those sources. [OpenVRML from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvrml/files/openvrml/0.18.3/openvrml-0.18.3.tar.gz/download)

should I run just do this? :

```
./configure
make
```

Any help is very appreciated , thanks ;)

Comment: btw, make does not work here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give any information about what sorts of failures you've seen so it's difficult to guess.  However, it looks like one fix for an `openvrml` build problem was [just checked-in to macports](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/22185).  If the problem description looks familiar, you might want to try it again:

```
sudo port sync
sudo port install openvrml
```

Comment: thank you very much Ned, I updated macports and this time I could install it.
But now I am having trouble using it. 
The post is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678828/openvrml-in-snow-leopard-from-macports

Comment: Glad it helped.  P.S. Don't forget to accept answers so that answerers will get points.